# AngularJS routing is not working: no events on link clicks, no $routeParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Somehow my app stopped working during development and I really cannot get what's wrong with it.

I've removed everything, the only code remaining is:

```
function handlerControl($scope, $routeParams, $location){
    $scope.route = $routeParams;
}

var app = angular.module('Hello', []).config(
    function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/:a/:b', {controller: handlerControl});
    }
);
```

and html is

```
<body ng-app="Hello">

<div ng-controller="handlerControl">
    {{route}}
</div>

</body>
```

omitting head part with including everything.

When I go to

```
http://helloday/#/a/b/
```

I'm getting an empty hash while expecting to get {a: 'a', b: 'b'}

What I'm doing wrong?

Bit modified(to make it work) jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wWDj2/http://jsfiddle.net/wWDj2/

Answer (score 6):

Routing requires you use ngView, and that you specify either a `template` or a `templateUrl`:

App code.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.when('/foo/:id', {
        controller: 'FooCtrl',
        template: '<h1>Foo {{id}}</h1>'
   })
   .when('/bar/:test', {
        controller: 'BarCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'bartemplate.html'
   })
   .otherwise({ 
        controller: 'DefaultCtrl',
        template: '<h1>This is the default</h1>'
   });
});

app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
   $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
});

app.controller('BarCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
   $scope.test = $routeParams.test;
});

app.controller('DefaultCtrl', function($scope){});
```

Your main page's markup:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <a href="#/foo/123">Foo 123</a>
   <a href="#/bar/blah">Bar Blah</a>
   <a href="#">Default route</a>
   <hr/>
   <div ng-view>
       <!-- your processed view will show up here -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"Routing requires you use ngView, and that you specify either a template or a templateUrl"*. Any idea why this is **mandatory** and if there's a way to get around this?

Comment: @TTT: You can always specify a templateUrl, then use it in a script tag on your page: `<script id="my/template/url/here.html"> template stuff here </script>`.